# Select option box based on value of an input box in appended selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have a selectbox that shows number of childeren. when the user change selectbox it appends selectboxes for showing age of each child. moreover I have an input box with type readonly .
how can I select each child age based on value of input type with classname age ?

> i get values like this : 1,2

the first value is for the first selectbox and the second value is for second selectbox .
and if user change select box froM the first i want to clear the selected option.

is there a way to do this ?
here is my snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.countRoom').find('.childnum').val($('.childcount').val());
  $('.countRoom').find('.childnum').change()
})
function childAge(a){
  $(a).each(function(){
    age=$(a).val();
    
    $(a).closest(".countRoom").find(".selectAge").empty();
    for(var j=1;j<=age;j++){
      $(a).closest(".countRoom").css("width","100%").find(".selectAge").append('<div class="age"><label>Age of Child' + j + '</label><select name="childage" class="childage form-control"><option value="1">Up to 1 years</option><option value="2">1 to 2 years</option></select></div>');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countRoom">
     children
     <select onChange="childAge(this)" class="childnum">
      <option value="0"> 0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
     </select>
   <input type="text" class="childcount" value="2" readonly style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" class="age" value="1,2" readonly style="background:green;">
     
    <div class="selectAge"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I am unable to understand what you actually want now? Please clarify

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh Actually i want to select those option based on value in input class age. for example if the first value in inputbox was 1 , select that option with value 1 in my first selectbox.. if the second value was 2 select the option with value 2 in my second selectbox.

Comment: And what happen if some-one write:- 1,2,3,4,5,444 in your text-box?

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh it is not possible . they are constant from 0 to 11

Comment: but any-one can write anything in your text-box.

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh no it is a readonly box i mentioned it

Comment: so value will never changed? just you want that based on value first and second-box option is came selected accordingly?

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh no will never change. i get the value of this input from Url on page load . i want to select option based on values of input

Comment: So why you are removing(hiding) them on the selection of  children select box?

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh it is a research for a hotel reservation. maybe the user wants to change count of childeren or again add them . but if the user remove them once there is no need to show the previous values on each of them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get the value of `input.age` and then split it. After that you can use that value to set `selected` attribute in your `loop`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.countRoom').find('.childnum').val($('.childcount').val());
  $('.countRoom').find('.childnum').change()
})

function childAge(a) {
  var ageVals = $('input.age').val().split(',')
  $('input.age').val(',')
  $(a).each(function() {
    age = $(a).val();

    $(a).closest(".countRoom").find(".selectAge").empty();
    for (var j = 1; j <= age; j++) {
      $(a).closest(".countRoom").css("width", "100%").find(".selectAge").append('<div class="age"><label>Age of Child' + j + '</label><select name="childage" class="childage form-control"><option value="1" ' + (ageVals[j - 1] == 1 ? 'selected' : '') + '>Up to 1 years</option><option value="2" ' + (ageVals[j - 1] == 2 ? 'selected' : '') + '>1 to 2 years</option></select></div>');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="countRoom">
  children
  <select onChange="childAge(this)" class="childnum">
      <option value="0"> 0 </option>
      <option value="1"> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
     </select>
  <input type="text" class="childcount" value="2" readonly style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" class="age" value="1,2" readonly style="background:green;">

  <div class="selectAge"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie--Anantsingh yeah it is what I want